# Requirejs is loading the same Javascript files multiple times

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I am using requirejs as the module loader in my Typescript project. I found out that some modules (js files) are loaded twice and some are loaded three times and this causes problems. What can be the reason? Can it be because the relative paths are different when importing these modules? That's what I'm suspicious of. How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of another answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16380692/6305376, I added the following to my `data-main` file and it worked:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './', 
 }
)
```

Apparently, Requirejs creates different modules for the same file if it is imported with different relative urls from different modules. So, setting a base url as such forces all the Requirejs modules to have their name relative to the outermost folder, making a one-to-one mapping between the modules and their names. So each module is loaded only once.

Answer (score 0):

> I found out that some modules (js files) are loaded twice and some are loaded three times and this causes problems.

Make sure you don't use file extensions. Its a known issue (module `x.js` is distinct from `x`)

Comment: I'm not, actually I am using the auto-complete feature of Visual Studio for imports so they are all in standard form.